# Saving a File into a Proper Location in Android

Tags: android, file, bitmap, save

I need to programmatically save a bitmap file produced by my application into a directory. The user will be able to take it from its location via regular file explorers. Which way should I follow to determine a location for it?

For example:

1. Check the external sd card
2. If the external card exists, then save it there
3. If not, then save it in the internal memory

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

This wili give you primary memory dir root path of your mobile so from this u can set your file root oath or directory

Comment: Do you advise me to attempt to store my file to an external memory at the first step?

Comment: if you want to store inside in any folder then take this path in one string and just concatenate with "/foldername/foldername" give any folder name with this "/" sign u reached at your dir path from this Environment.getExternalStorageState(); u get first root dir i think u understand what i trying to say